# Best way to display data in a listbox from DB in C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have a local database, which holds records for cars, it has fields ID(ai, primary), plateNumber, Comments, ect..
Also I have a form with ListBox, button "Checked", and many text fields.

I am using winforms, and every time I run the application, constructor retrieves all the records from the db which have the bool field named "checked" == null, and displays the carnumbers in the Listview. When a specific plateNumber in that listBox is clicked, the other column data for the selected carPlate should appear in the textfields, but the

Problem is that there might be more records with the same plateNumber where "Checked" == null(true otherwise).

Question: how to keep the information about the specific plate number "behind the scenes" and when person clicks to select the platenumber from the listBox, it displays the data about the current(by id) platenumber in the form. Note that, if person clicks a "Checked" button on the form, it stores "TRUE" in the DB "checked" field and removes the specific carPlate from the listBox, and the next time application is launched it won't display that specific ID. In web I use hidden fields with javascript to achieve this, in C# I'm not aware how you keep information like that, I'm leaning towards arrays? 
Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Post your code!!!

Comment: wouldn't your constructor itself have the data "behind the scenes" already?

Comment: Yes, but the quesiton is, how to store the data about specific car, and how to retrieve it once I choose the plate number(there can be doublicates too) from the listBox, and how to tell which ID goes with what plateNumber in the listbox which was clicked?

Comment: Can you try reducing your problem to a much simpler one that still exhibits the behavior you're trying to understand? Your example and explanation are a little hard to follow. Like, is the "checked" field really relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViews are populated with ListViewItems. The ListViewItem class has a Tag property, where you can store anything you want. Your "hidden" or "behind the scenes" data can be stored there.